# Grid Not Working on Portfolio Animation images

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-grid

Hello Im trying to add this portoflio animation I found on codepen https://codepen.io/konyali/pen/WZQKwG

[image]

to my website http://ruben123.com/ in the portoflio section. when I used all of the CDN's including bootstrap everything looked fine but when I got rid of the bootstrap cdn all of the images became the same size and stacked.

[image]

The reason why I got rid of the bootstrap cdn is because I dont want import an entire framework to my website only just to use the grid system when I can use css grid myself.

The problem is I tried adding css grid myself and I think I did everything right but for some reason it is not working. (Im using Scss in the code below)

```js
$('.filters ul li').click(function(){
    $('.filters ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
    var data = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: data
    })
  });
  
  var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({
    itemSelector: ".all",
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: ".all"
    }
  })
```

```css
#portfolio-animation {

    .section {
        padding: 30px 0;
        color: #333;
        .top-side {
            text-align: center;
            .title {
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 15px;
                display: inline-block;
                &:after {
                    content: "";
                    display: block;
                    width: 50%;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #494949;
                    margin: 8px auto;
                }
            }
            h2 {
                font-weight: 700;
            }
        }
    }


    .section.portfolio {
        .filters {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 50px;
            ul {
                padding: 0;
                li {
                    list-style: none;
                    display: inline-block;
                    padding: 20px 30px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    position: relative;
                    &:after {
                        content: "";
                        display: block;
                        width: calc(0% - 60px);
                        position: absolute;
                        height: 2px;
                        background: #333;
                        transition: width 350ms ease-out;
                    }
                    &:hover {
                        &:after {
                            width: calc(100% - 60px);
                            transition: width 350ms ease-out;
                        }
                    }
                }
                li.active {
                    &:after {
                        width: calc(100% - 60px);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .filters-content {
            margin-top: 50px;

                .grid {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
                // background-color: #2196F3;
                // padding: 10px;
            
                    .show {
                        opacity: 1;
                        visibility: visible;
                        transition: all 350ms;
                    }
                    .hide {
                        opacity: 0;
                        visibility: hidden;
                        transition: all 350ms;
                    }
                    .item {
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        margin-bottom: 30px;
                        .p-inner {
                            padding: 20px 30px;
                            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                            h5 {
                                font-size: 15px;
                            }
                            .cat {
                                font-size: 13px;
                            }
                        }
                        img {

                            width: 100%;
                        }

                    }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```html
    <div id="portfolio-animation" class="py-2">
        <section class="portfolio section">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="top-side">
                <!-- <h4 class="title">MY WORKS</h4> -->
                <h2 class="section-title">PORTFOLIO</h2>
              </div>
              
              <div class="filters">
                <ul>
                  <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
                  <li data-filter=".corporate">Corporate</li>
                  <li data-filter=".personal">Personal</li>
                  <li data-filter=".agency">Agency</li>
                  <li data-filter=".portal">Portal</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              
              <div class="filters-content">
                <div class="row grid">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 all corporate">
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/documentation/doc-images/muffin-options/custom-js.png" alt="Work 1">
                      <div class="p-inner">
                        <h5>Work 1</h5>
                        <div class="cat">Corporate</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 all personal">
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/documentation/doc-images/muffin-options/custom-js.png" alt="Work 1">
                      <div class="p-inner">
                        <h5>Work 1</h5>
                        <div class="cat">Personal</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 all agency">
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/documentation/doc-images/muffin-options/custom-js.png" alt="Work 1">
                      <div class="p-inner">
                        <h5>Work 1</h5>
                        <div class="cat">Agency</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 all portal">
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/documentation/doc-images/muffin-options/custom-js.png" alt="Work 1">
                      <div class="p-inner">
                        <h5>Work 1</h5>
                        <div class="cat">Portal</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </section>
    </div>








    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Portoflio CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.4/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE: I couldnt find an answer on here so I went to codepen and found another photo gallery filter that doesnt use bootstrap.

Comment: I tried playing around with the CSS on your site to use a CSS grid layout, and the JavaScript animations are not as fluid with the grid layout. For that reason, I'd probably just stick with using the Bootstrap related CSS for rows and columns.

Comment: Ok thanks for taking the time to look at my site and play with the code. I’m try the code below if it doesn’t work then I will try this approach.

Comment: how do I find and add the bootstrap css?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this css code, taken from Bootstrap cdn

```
.row:after,.row:before{display:table;content:" "}.row:after{clear:both}
.col-sm-4{position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;float:left;width:33.33333333%}
```

Comment: I tried the code you gave me but all of the portfolio images ended up on the left  it only fit 2 portfolio pieces per row instead of 3. Also it added padding between portfolio image and white box that says "work 1"